# Solutions of four linear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have a set of four differential equations represented by the following matrix equation:

```
x1'[t] == (-p + I q)*x1[t] + I*m*x3[t];
x2'[t] == (-p + I q)*x2[t] + I*m*x4[t]; 
x3'[t] == (r + I s)*x3[t] + I*m*x1[t]; 
x4'[t] == (r + I s)*x4[t] + I*m*x2[t];
```

Here $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$ and $m$ are reals. How can I solve this system? Given that $x_1(0)=1, x_2(0)=0,x_3(0)=1,x_4(0)=0.$

Comment: Have a look at `DSolve` and `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the help and type the keywords of the task you have. Then read the documentation. [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) should become apparent as a possible avenue to explore. Notice the syntax and the examples. Reproduce the examples but using your own equations.

[image]

```
DSolve[
 {
  x1'[t] == (-p + I q)*x1[t] + I*m*x3[t],
  x2'[t] == (-p + I q)*x2[t] + I*m*x4[t],
  x3'[t] == (r + I s)*x3[t] + I*m*x1[t],
  x4'[t] == (r + I s)*x4[t] + I*m*x2[t],
  x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, x3[0] == 0, x4[0] == 0
  }
 , {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t]}
 , t
 ]
(* {{x1[t] -> 0, x3[t] -> 0, x2[t] -> 0, x4[t] -> 0}} *)
```

As pointed out in the comments I didn't use your boundary conditions. My system is somehow simpler. You get the idea, the rest you need to fix yourself.

Comment: Very good explanation. If you choose correct initial conditions MMA gives a nontrivial solution.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Then the answer is too long to fit the screen! In reality I didn't bother so put the correct numbers, I'm focusing in the process. :)

Comment: Nice video :) Just for the record: with the ICs from the OP, `FullSimplify` gives a [not so complicated solution](https://imgur.com/a/YYS8ThS).